# C++ on Opencv 3

Tags: c++, opencv

I am not good with C++ but am starting to learn. I learn by looking at other people's code.

I am looking at a SVM tutorial on Opencv [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d1/d73/tutorial_introduction_to_svm.html)

I do not understand the part on

(Mat_(1,2) << j,i);

1. What does it mean by Mat_ (1,2)? Specifically what does the _ represent?
2. Why is j and i fed into the matrix? Shouldn't it be i and j, where i = rows and j = columns?

   ```
    // Show the decision regions given by the SVM
    Vec3b green(0,255,0), blue (255,0,0);
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
        {
            Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1,2) << j,i);
            float response = svm->predict(sampleMat);
            if (response == 1)
                image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)  = green;
            else if (response == -1)
                image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)  = blue;
        }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `(Mat_<float>(1,2) << j,i)`: creates a 1-by-2 matrix and fills it with the values of `i` and `j`.
2. The function `cv::Mat::operator()` requires you to specify row (`i`) and column (`j`) but the data that goes into the function `predict()` simply uses an other order. From the tutorial:

> [...] an image is traversed interpreting its pixels as points of the Cartesian plane. [...]

Comment: ok i understand it's creating a 1x2 matrix but i still don't understand why it should be j and i, instead of i and j.

Comment: OpenCV uses the order `i`-`j`. The Cartesian coordinates use the order `j`-`i`. It's just a convention.

Comment: It's not just opencv. Matrices are commonly accessed by row, column

Answer (score 1):

Names in C++ may have trailing underscores. "Mat_" is an ordinary name of a function. In this case, Mat_ is related to the Mat class, but not the same. It is used to create a matrix of type Mat and at the same time specify its characteristics.

In this particular case, the sampleMat object will have 1 column and 2 rows, so it will look like a vector of dimension 2, and the values (j,i) will be assigned to it.

More specifically:

- `Mat_` is the name of the function
- `<float>` is the template type that specifies what kind of elements will the matrix contain
- `(1,2)` are the initialisation parameters, which create a matrix with one column and two rows.
- `<<` is an overloaded operator, which indicates that the following parameters will be assigned to the matrix when it is initialised
- `j,i` are the two parameters assigned to the matrix